# Can I call any function a signal?

Tags: definitions, geometric-deep-learning, signal-processing

While reading the `Notation` of the paper titled  [Geometric Deep Learning Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.13478.pdf#page=7), I came across the following notations.

$$
\Omega = \text{ Domain} \\
 u = \text{Point on domain} \\
x(u) \in \mathcal{X}(\Omega, C) = \text{ Signal on the domain of the form } x : \Omega \rightarrow C
$$

Mathematically, [a signal is just a function](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee269/Lecture1.pdf#page=11).

But, every function may not be a signal. There may be some distinction between a mathematical function and a signal.

When can I call any mathematical function a signal? And what is $\mathcal{X}$ in the notation given?

Comment: I think $\chi$ is the set of all the signals over the domain.